# Using contains with Jenkins expression and env var

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create a `Jenkinsfile` to handle different steps in prod vs dev environments. I was attempting to use the [`anyOf` pattern with an `expression`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) that checks the `JOB_URL` environmental variable to determine which build server/build instruction to follow.

Jenkinsfile ends up looking something like the below:

```
stage('In Prod') {
    when {
        allOf {
            expression { params.P1 == 'x' }
            expression { params.P2 == 'y' }
            expression { env.JOB_URL.contains('prod_server.com') }
        }
    }
    ...
}
stage('In Dev') {
    when {
        allOf {
            expression { params.P1 == 'x' }
            expression { params.P2 == 'y' }
            expression { env.JOB_URL.contains('dev_server.com') }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Expected Behavior:

- In Dev -> run `In Dev` step
- In Prod -> run `In Prod` step

Actual Behavior:

- In Dev -> run `In Prod` AND `In Dev` step
- In Prod -> run `In Prod` step

Yes, I have checked to make sure that `JOB_URL` on the `dev` does not contain `prod_server.com`.

I have also tried `!env.JOB_URL.contains('dev_server.com')` as an additional expression for the `prod` step with the same result.

I only know enough `groovy` to get through Jenkins, and am somewhat new to Jenkins pipeline syntax, so maybe I've misunderstood the behavior here, but from what I understand from the Jenkins `expression` documentation:

> when returning strings from your expressions they must be
>   converted to booleans or return null to evaluate to false. Simply
>   returning "0" or "false" will still evaluate to "true".

And as a sanity check, I confirmed that the `groovy` documentation says [`contains` should be returning a `boolean`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression comparator in the expression to check the one of these environment variables:

- built-in: `JENKINS_URL` and `BUILD_URL` ([source built-in var](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables))
- plugin-provided `JOB_URL` (exists but can't find source)

Note: environment variable are exposed through the reserved environment variable map `env` ([using env variable](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)), e.g. `server_url = env.JENKINS_URL`.

Try something like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    parameters {
        string(name: 'P1', defaultValue: 'x', description: '')
        string(name: 'P2', defaultValue: 'y', description: '')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Init') {
            steps {
                echo "params = ${params.toString()}"
                echo "env.JENKINS_URL = ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
            }
        }
        stage('In Prod') {
            when {
                allOf {
                    expression { params.P1 == 'x' }
                    expression { params.P2 == 'y' }
                    expression { env.JENKINS_URL ==~ /.*prod_server.com.*/ }
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Prod"
            }
        }
        stage('In Dev') {
            when {
                allOf {
                    expression { params.P1 == 'x' }
                    expression { params.P2 == 'y' }
                    expression { env.JENKINS_URL ==~ /.*dev_server.com.*/ }
                }
            }

            steps {
                echo "DEV"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are we sure this works? I have a similar example but I'm always getting "No such property: JOB_URL for class: WorkflowScript"

Comment: Thank you @MiguelCosta, good point. JOB_URL is an environment variable, thus needs to be accessed via `env` : `env.JOB_URL`. I couldn't find confirmation that `JOB_URL` is natively available so I replaced it with `JENKINS_URL`.